# Open source personal journal

Tags: open-source, markdown, static-site-generator, journal

I'm looking for a open source personal journal

At this moment I'm using Nikola with kramdown. But what I'm searching for should have:

- Static generator.
- Built-in web server.
- Nice editor. I have no problem to start to write my post with vim, but then, once the post is published, it could be great a web editor, for example, to tick a task done. It would be great if I can edit and save the changes of an existing post.
- Support either GFM markdown, kramdown or multi-markdown.

And it should be open source.

I've used rednotebook, but it's a desktop app. And I'd want to use in the browser and only if I need it to deploy sometime in an external web server.

Comment: You have a server to host it? Or you want a hosted (yet open source) solution?

Answer (score -2):

Notebook
http://www.joelotter.com/kajero/

- editor
- notebook-like format

Book like
https://www.gitbook.com/

- can be used to publish book

Comment: Static notes
http://dynalon.github.io/mdwiki/#!index.md

Wiki
https://torchpad.com

Comment: For each proposed solution, you must explain how it satisfies each bullet in the requirements of the question.